# Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web unable to find MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I understand there are various posts similar to this issue but there are none which match the problem I am having.

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web, but I cannot create an MVC 4 web application as this option is not available when I create a new project.

I have tried to find the tools in the NuGet package manager but I have had no success.

Using the web platform installer I have managed to download an ASP.NET MVC 4 with language packs (2012) but that hasn't seemed to have any effect on my visual studio (I'm not even sure if its installed correctly).

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is the options I have when I select "New Project":

[image]

Comment: What framework version are you selecting in the new project dialog?  MVC 4 may not be available if you select newer framework versions.  In VS2013, it only shows up if I select Framework 4.

Comment: are you suggesting that I should download the 2013 or 2012 express for web editions instead to get the framework I am after?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that at all... Could you post a screenshot of the New Project dialog?  Having the full version, I'm not sure what limitations the Express version has.

Comment: Also, do you have the latest Update version of VS2015?  Looks like MVC4 tooling was absent from the RTM version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591926.aspx

Comment: Hello, thanks for your post, il download that update shortly and will post back my results

Comment: downloaded the latest version via the link you sent me and its made no change. The closest I can get to an MVC application is downloading one of the samples which isn't what i'm looking for.

Comment: In the New Project window, the first central dropdown (directly above Class Library), you can set the target framework.  What options do you have if you select `4.0` instead of `4.5.2`?